# How to provide BindingContext to Control template

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, controltemplate

I have a template defined in App.Xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HomePageTemplate">
            <Label Text="{Binding MyLabelText}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And I use it in my Home page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Converters"
            x:Class="App.Views.HomePage"
            ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HomePageTemplate}">

</ContentPage>
```

I set the `BindingContext` of my `Homepage` in code behind.

Now shouldn't the `ControlTemplate` inherit the HomePage's `BindingContext` ? Because I thought that was the case but my `Label` doesn't keep the text from `MyLabelText`. What's the work around to work with `Bindings` in these templates ?

EDIT:

Using this option

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HomePageTemplate">
            <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.MyLabelText}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Also does not work for me, because I use the `ControlTemplate`in the header of the `HomePage` and not inside it's body.

This works **BUT IT'S NOT** what I'm looking for:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Converters"
            x:Class="App.Views.HomePage"
            >
  <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HomePageTemplate}" />
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Have a look at the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/template-binding#binding-a-bindableproperty-to-a-viewmodel-property) and also samples there.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Can you take a look at my edited question ? thx for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ControlTemplate` controls the binding is slightly different. Have a look at these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/template-binding

Assuming that the `MyLabelText` property is part of the `BindingContext` of the parent control your code could look like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HomePageTemplate">
            <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.MyLabelText }"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because my `ControlTemplate` is inside the ContentPage properties, and not in the body. Only if I placed the `ControlTemplate` inside the body this option would work

Comment: @Greggz You marked this as correct? Explain please, I am having the same issue as you.

Answer (score 0):

App.xaml should have a BindingContext. Let's call it AppViewmodel, with a namespace vm (or any other key) defined at the top of App.xaml. This AppViewmodel can be bound to from within the ControlTemplate. In this example a button (placed in a stacklayout) is bound to a command named AppCommand, which resides in AppViewmodel. When this ControlTemplate is applied in a ContentPage, it binds to the ViewModel of App.xaml, not to the VM of that particular ContentPage. Perhaps the latter is also possible, for example by choosing the right settings for RelativeSource and AncestorType, but I haven't figured that out.
[see also](https://www.davidbritch.com/2019/11/bind-from-controltemplate-to-viewmodel.html)

```
     <ControlTemplate x:Key="HomePageTemplate">
            <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <Button 
Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:AppViewModel}}, Path=AppCommand}"
                            />
            </StackLayout>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone its interested, the way this works its just adding Path after TemplateBinding, specifying BindingContext on it and then the public var name:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HomePageTemplate">
        <Label Text="{ TemplateBinding Path=BindingContext.MyLabelText }"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```